# Meteor - NPM Package works on localhost but not dev server or prod server

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, npm-install

I am currently still using Meteor 1.2 and Im trying to get the node-mailjet npm module working in my app.

I have it fully working when on the local host but when I deploy to the server I get the following error when I try to send email:

Cannot find module 'node-mailjet'

Below is the code I am using that works perfect on the localhost:3000.  I am using mup to deploy to server and then it fails there when sending email.

```
var mailjet = Npm.require('node-mailjet')
            .connect(Meteor.settings.mailJetKey1, Meteor.settings.mailJetKey2);

        var request = mailjet
            .post("send")
            .request({
                "FromEmail":            "info@dynatraildispatch.com",
                "FromName":             companyProfile.companyBillingEmail,
                "Subject":              'Invoice - ' + trip.tripNumber + " From " + companyProfile.companyName,
                "Html-part":            htmlBody,
                "Recipients":           toEmailAddresses,
                "Headers":              {"Reply-To":companyProfile.companyBillingEmail},
                "Attachments":          emailAttachments
            });
        request
            .on('success', function (response, body) {
                console.log (response.statusCode, body);
            })
            .on('error', function (err, response) {
                console.log (response.statusCode, err);
            });
```

This is the first npm package I have tried to use and this is frustrating.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  Packages.json file:

```
{
  "node-mailjet": "1.1.0"
}
```

Comment: How does your `packages.json` file look like?

Comment: added to the original question

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious: you do have `meteorhacks:npm` package installed, right?

Comment: do have what what sorry?

Comment: yes I do i have that installed

Comment: Sorry, I've accidentally added half a comment. It's updated now :-)

Comment: the wierd thing is that it works perfect when on localhost but not on the server

Comment: Which meteor version do you have? For meteor 1.3 you want to use `meteor npm install`. It seems that the package hasn't been installed on the server. DId you run npm install in your deployment?

Comment: I am using 1.2 still and I have tried meteor npm, just npm and a couple other varients. Am I needing to log into the server and install it there?